# jaxws-maven-plugin, maven-enunciate-plugin example?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, enunciate

I've inherited a project that contains many jaxws services.  I want to add another one and am trying to duplicate a similar working example.  I can test that one like this

```
./soapget.sh soap_serial.xml r.xml
```

where soapget.sh is

```
    #!/bin/bash

    wget "http://localhost:5032/VCWH_QueryService/soap/SettopChannelMapResourceService" --post-file=$1 --header="Content-Type: text/xml" -O $2
```

This produces a good response, captured in r.xml.

Like the working service, my new service uses three classes.  The code compiles ok, assembles into a .war file, and deploys. Now when I try the same thing for the new service I wrote

```
./bsg.sh soap_rate.xml r2.xml
```

where bsg.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash

    wget "http://localhost:5032/VCWH_QueryService/soap/BsgHandleResourceService" --post-file=$1 --header="Content-Type: text/xml" -O $2
```

I get the useless error

```
2015-11-23 20:26:52 ERROR 500: Internal Server Error
```

The log files for the project do not contain any more info either.
There are just too many black boxes interacting that I can't figure out what's going on... Maven-Enunciate-Plugin, jax-ws, Java, etc.

For example, how does calling BSGHandleResourceService find its way to the actual code, one of which is called BSGHandleResource.java?  Normally I would make those hooks in the web.xml file but that has been taken over by the black boxes.

Are there any jax-ws/maven experts out there that can shed some light?

Comment: Where does `enunciate` come into the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find and fix the problem by sending a soap request to the service using SoapUI.  That returned useful error messages whereas the other method did not.